# Drupal 7 API call to return progess status

Tags: api, drupal-7, response, progress

I can make a call that expects one response, which can be fired over and over to see the progress, but that is not very 'user' friendly, so I would like to have one call that stays open throughout the entire process. 
Each finished step of the process will send a response. for the sake of simplicity, lets say I want to return a new message every 30 seconds and the entire process takes 3 minutes. How can I do this by performing only one API call ? In essence I would like to 'stream' the progress of my process.

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking for Drupal Batch API.

A good sample example is provided in Drupal.org Batch API overview page..

Check it out here: [Source](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/batch-api/overview)

Comment: So i don't have to worry about keep-alive headers and stuff so that I can send responses in multiple steps? (I have no experience with this)

Comment: By the way i return a json to the application